# innerHTML failing on case

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a interactive application with a text field to practice javascript, but I am finding for validation, that the case does not display innerHTML text though the rest of the function loops though. text.innerHTML works in all other cases, am I missing something here?

**Javascript**

```
function getNum(input){
    if (isNaN(input)) {
        oldstate = state-1;
        state = 33;
        console.log("Loading error Message...");
        act();
    }
    else{return(parseInt(input, 10));}
}

function act(){
    console.log("Case: "+state);
    input = inputf.value;
    inputf.value="";
    switch(state){
        case 0:
            name = input;
            text.innerHTML = "Well, hello there, "+name+"! Nice to meet you. What's your age?";
            break;
        case 1:
            text.innerHTML = "Loading...";
            age = getNum(input);
            text.innerHTML = "So, "+name+" you are "+age+" years old!";
            break;
        case 33:
            text.innerHTML = "That is NOT a number! Hit Submit to Return.";
            console.log("Error Successfully loaded!");
            state = oldstate;
            break;
    }
    state=+1;
}


function getStr(input){

}
```

Here is my HTML with the text field id's. Any optimization suggestions would also be appreciated.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>titles are lame</title>
        <link/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
        <script></script>
    </head>
    <body>
<div id="wrapper"><div id="text">First, let's have your name.</div>
    <br>
    <input type='text' id="input"><input type="submit"id="submit" onclick="act()">

</div>
    <script>
    var state = 0;
    var inputf = document.getElementById("input");
    var text = document.getElementById('text');
    var input, name, age,oldstate;

    document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {

    // Enter is pressed
    if (e.keyCode == 13) { act(); }
}, false);
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: if you will press on the `enter` it will work... so what is the problem?

Comment: For me the "this is NOT a number" error does not show if you debug and do not give a numerical value when asking for age. It instead will bounce and say you are undefined years old. It is supposed to throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

I think I know what the problem is. In case 1, you call the `getNum` method, it executes just fine in the correct case, calls the `act()` method, enters case 33 correctly, returning an error and... then keeps executing case 1. Because you didn't specify a return statement in the first case of the `getNum` function, age has an undefined value. It should work fine if you add this line:

`if (!age) return;`

just after calling the `getNum` method in case 1.

EDIT: I just realized you should also check how state is managed after detecting an error. Adding the line I gave you will leave a state of 33.

Answer (score 0):

Click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/liorlolo/Vv9AW/1/) to see the answer..

```
 act() //Changed
```